# Cannot find any information on what [ds:0x18] refers to in the NASM documentation

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

> Cannot find any information on what the instruction `mov eax, [ds:0x18]` does in the NASM documentation.

Looking through the NASM documentation it's not written what the semantics of `[ds:0x18]` is, except that it is valid syntax for effective addressing.

Can someone clarify the function of this syntax, and if possible refer to a place in the documentation where its semantics is given implicitly?

Comment: Did that line come from a disassembly? The `ds:` part is a segment override, but as Bo Persson mentions in his answer, `ds` would have been the default here so specifying it is redundant. Some disassemblers might still display addresses like that though.

Comment: Just a pointless addition to Bo's answer: [MOV instruction](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_176.html), the relevant variant in this case is `8B /r` `MOV r32,r/m32`, moving 32 bits of memory content (at address ds:0x18) into 32 bit register (eax).

Answer (score 3):

It just loads `eax` from address `0x18` in the data segment. As the data segment `ds` is the default segment for data loads, using it as a prefix is redundant, except in very special cases.

It would be more interesting with a `mov eax, [cs:0x18]` for loading something from the code segment instead.

Comment: Thank you @BoPersson. Do you know why NASM don't mention it? Is it because the syntax is inherited from Intel's x86 manual?

Comment: But aren't all segments the same in a flat memory model?

Comment: In some cases, `fs` and/or `gs` are used to point to thread information / thread local storage.

Comment: In normal 32-bit code on a normal OS, `cs:0x18` isn't particularly interesting, because @Nicolas is right about the flat memory model.  Small absolute addresses are common with `fs:` or `gs:` for thread-local storage, but never with ss/cs/ds/es in "normal" code.

Comment: @PeterCordes: And that's because ss/cs/ds/es refers to the same segment? But according to Intel's Manual, CS typically point to the code segment, while SS/DS/ES point to the data/stack segment (two segments in total). Are the code and stack segments identical?

Comment: @NicolasLykkeIversen: No, I think `cs` will usually index a different segment descriptor than the others.  The attributes of that segment descriptor determine whether the CPU is in 32-bit mode or 64-bit mode.  I don't know enough about segments to know whether ss/ds/es usually all hold the same value on Linux for example, but probably they do.  But they definitely all have the same base=0 & limit=2^32-1 or 2^64-1.  (Segments are allowed to overlap, and in the normal case they all cover the entire virtual address space, except fs/gs.)

Comment: But since segments can overlap, can offsets within the data segment refer to places within the code segment? In this case, since the data segment is readable, the code segment could be overwritten?